# USB drive does not pop up in Dock

Tags: usb

When inserting a USB drive on my laptop, the drive does not popup in Dock like other distributions.  To get to the USB drive, you have to open up a folder and select the USB drive.  Is this done on purpose or is it a bug?  If is done on purpose, is there a way to change the settings so that the USB shows up on the Dock when inserted?

Thank you.